# How to copy a directory from one host to another host?

Tags: perl, directory, copy, scp

I want to copy a directory from one host to another host using SCP
I tried with following syntax

```
my $src_path="/abc/xyz/123/";
my $BASE_PATH="/a/b/c/d/"; 
my $scpe = Net::SCP::Expect->new(host=> $host, user=>$username, password=>$password);
$scpe->scp -r($host.":".$src_path, $dst_path);
```

i am getting the errror like no such file or directory.can you help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

According to the example given in the manpage, you don't need to repeat the host in the call, if you already passed it as an option.

from http://search.cpan.org/~djberg/Net-SCP-Expect-0.12/Expect.pm:

```
Example 2 - uses constructor, shorthand scp:

my $scpe = Net::SCP::Expect->new(host=>'host', user=>'user', password=>'xxxx');

$scpe->scp('file','/some/dir'); # 'file' copied to 'host' at '/some/dir'
```

Besides, is this "-r" a typo? If you want to copy recursively, you need to set recursive => "yes" in the options hash.